# Find returning nothing because of how I define a range

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I am new to vba, so sometimes I don't know fully how the programming language works.

I am having trouble with a code which is suposed to get me the address of a cell based on a condition. When I apply `.find()` whith a generic and non dynamic range it works but when I try to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` and insert the last row as the end of my range in the `.find()`, it my variable returns nothing.

if I run the code like this:

```
Sub teste1()
Dim aux As Long
Dim aux2 As Range
Dim LR As Long

'LR = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

aux = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("namedsheet").Range("A1").Value
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Namedsheet").Range("A2:A1000") ' & LR)
    Set aux2 = .Find(What:=aux)
    If Not aux2 Is Nothing Then
        Cell_Split_R = Split(aux2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), "R")
        Cell_Split_C = Split(Cell_Split_R(1), "C")
        SCol = CLng(Cell_Split_C(0))
        SRow = CLng(Cell_Split_C(1))
    End If
End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("namedsheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("namedsheet").Cells(SCol, SRow).Value
MsgBox "terminou"
End Sub
```

it works.

but it I try to make a little more dynamic, with the SpecialCells, it does not work:

```
Sub teste1()
Dim aux As Long
Dim aux2 As Range
Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

aux = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("namedsheet").Range("A1").Value
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("namedsheet").Range("A2:A" & LR)
    Set aux2 = .Find(What:=aux)
    If Not aux2 Is Nothing Then
        Cell_Split_R = Split(aux2.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), "R")
        Cell_Split_C = Split(Cell_Split_R(1), "C")
        SCol = CLng(Cell_Split_C(0))
        SRow = CLng(Cell_Split_C(1))
    End If
End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("namedsheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value = _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("namedsheet").Cells(SCol, SRow).Value
MsgBox "terminou"
End Sub
```

I am expecting the range to go to the last cell with non blank values, and make it the range to apply the find method.
Right now when I do the second way the aux2 returns nothing, because the range is defined incorrectly.

Comment: A better method for finding the last row is `Worksheets("namedsheet").Columns(1).Rows(Worksheets("namedsheet").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: The most probable thing that would cause your method to not work properly is that you've not qualified your range with a worksheet. Fixing that would likely fix your code. That said, other things can cause issues such as empty but formatted cells are considered 'used' and so alter the returned value. There are other methods to find the end of a table, such as the example above provided by @Toddleson.

Comment: Also, you start with `Range("A:A")` - but `xlCellTypeLastCell` will return the bottom right cell of the used range of the sheet, regardless of the Range you specify. You could equally use `LR =Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`.

Comment: try `Range("A2:A" & Trim(Str(LR))) `, I think that will do. LR is a  Long not a String.  Yo have to use Trim because Srt usually adds a leading space before the number  in the converted string